# What is the most popular cross-platform mobile development kit available?

Tags: mobile, cross-platform, ria, toolkit

I'm a .NET/Flex web/windows developer about to make the plunge into mobile development. I was wondering what toolkit other mobile developers use to build their applications.

Is there any toolkit that works on all mobile devices, that provides a rich interface, preferably with touch capability? Ease of development would be a bonus.

What framework do you recommend? What are its advantages and limitations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is far more generalized and covers a broad view of mobile development. Mobile development can be of many types depending on many factors like:

1. Execution environments
2. Platform development environment

You can check [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_application_development) for a generalized idea of what a mobile development can be and what types of developments can be done for what.

Comment: Another place to check to gain better understanding is this post about mobile cross platform UIs: http://www.visionmobile.com/blog/2011/06/platform-x-how-cross-platform-tools-can-end-the-os-wars/